# Javascript: foreach skipping the first index (0)

Tags: javascript, foreach

A somewhat tilted question which I didn't manage to figure out.

I'd like to generate an object from two arrays and give them keys, like this:

```
 var A = [1, 2, 3, 4]; var B = [7, 8, 9, 19];

 [ { "x": 1, "y": 7 }, { "x": 2, "y": 8 }, { "x": 3, "y": 9 }, { "x":
     4, "y": 19 } ]
```

I wrote the following code:

```
var myData = []; var A = [1, 2, 3, 4]; var B = [7, 8, 9, 19];

A.forEach( function (item, index) {     
myData.push( { x: A[item], y: B[item] });   
});
```

But the output of it was

```
[ { "x": 2, "y": 8 }, { "x": 3, "y": 9 }, { "x": 4, "y": 19 }, {} ]
```

By putting in [item - 1] in the function, it works as I'd like it to, but I can't understand why as the w3School example that I looked at seems very straightforward and works from index-0:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_foreach

My Fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/53p5b3w8/5/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are close, just replace `item` with `index`

```
A.forEach( function (item, index) {   
   myData.push( { x: A[index], y: B[index] });   
});
```

or simply

```
A.forEach( function (item, index) {   
   myData.push( { x: item, y: B[index] });   
});
```

Basically, when you say A[item], it takes `values`(1,2,3,4) instead of `index` (0,1,2,3).

**DEMO**

```js
var A = [1, 2, 3, 4]; var B = [7, 8, 9, 19];
var myData = [];
A.forEach( function (item, index) {   
       myData.push( { x: item, y: B[index] });   
});
document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify( myData, 0, 4 )
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `index` instead of `item` within your loop as you were iterating through the values in your array as opposed to the indices that you needed to reference :

```
A.forEach( function (item, index) {     
    myData.push( { x: A[index], y: B[index] });   
});
```

**Example**

```js
var myData = [];
var A = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var B = [7, 8, 9, 19];

A.forEach(function(item, index) {
  myData.push({
    x: A[item - 1],
    y: B[item - 1]
  });
});

console.log(myData);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(myData, null, 3);


var myData = [];
var A = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var B = [7, 8, 9, 19];

A.forEach(function(item, index) {
  myData.push({
    x: A[item],
    y: B[item]
  });
});

console.log(myData);
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(myData, null, 3);
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<br>
<p id="demo2"></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

that's what you need:

```
var c = A.map((item, index) => ({x: A[index], y: B[index}));
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to mention, you can also use map if `myData` is only gonna contain the two arrays combined:

```
var myData = A.map(function(item, index) {
  return { x: item, y: B[index] };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

array index will starts from 0

```
            A.forEach( function (item, index) {     
                myData.push( { x: A[index], y: B[index] });   
            });
```

If you are using array A for order you can do without using that array by following method

```
            B.forEach( function (item, index) {     
                myData.push( { x: index+1, y: B[index] });   
            });
```